# cppcheck detects a resource leak - a false negative?

Tags: c, c99, cppcheck

cppcheck detects a resorce leak in the code below.
I think it is a fals negative.
If not, can you explaint to me why it is a resource leak?

```
bool fileExists(const char* filename)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    bool result = (fp != NULL);
    if (result) fclose(fp);
    return result; // <-- (cppcheck error) Resource leak: fp
}
```

Comment: If you replace `if (result)` with `if (fp != NULL)` is there stil a resource leak reported?

Comment: What happens if you write it this way: `FILE *fp; if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {return false;} fclose(fp); return true;`

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but `fopen(filename, "r")` can also - on some systems - return `NULL` if `filename` is open for writing or exists but is protected to avoid opening.   That can't be dealt with in standard C - necessary to use system-specific APIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is false negative, cppcheck wrongly detects one *theoretically possible* branch when `fp` is not closed

I'd personally rewrite this code as:

```
FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
if (fp != NULL) {
    fclose(fp);
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: Even better: `if(fp) {...}`

Comment: @machine_1 Whether this is better or not is debatable.

Comment: @machine_1 you're right, it is absolutely valid to use `if(fp)`, just my personal preference to be more explicit